# Меню с выпадающим списком не закрывается после отведения курсора мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. У меня есть скрипт, который отвечает за выпадающее меню. Сейчас всё работает таким образом, что есть 3 пункта меню и каждый со своими подпунктами. Когда я навожу курсор мыши на пункт, то появляется выпадающий блок с подпунктами. Если навести курсор мыши на соседний пункт, то уже выпавший блок с подпунктами скроется и появится тот, на который был наведён курсор. Но я всё никак не могу сообразить, как мне сделать так, чтобы:

1. При отведении курсора мыши куда-то в сторону последний блок с выпадающими подпунктами скрывался
2. Чтобы можно было наводить курсором мыши на блок с выпадающими подпунктами и чтобы он не закрывался

JS:

```
$(() => {
    let dropdown = $('li .menu-link.drop-down'),
        itemlist = $('.menu-item-list'),
        w = $(window).width();

    dropdown.on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    dropdown.hover(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        let droplist = $(this).closest('li').find('.dropdown-list'),
            isHidden = droplist.is(':hidden');
        w > 992 ? itemlist.find('.dropdown-list').removeClass('active') : itemlist.find('.dropdown-list').slideUp(320)

        if(w > 992) droplist.toggleClass('active')
        if(isHidden && i < 992) droplist.slideDown(325);
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        let neighbor = $('li .menu-link ~ .dropdown-list');
        if(w > 992 && dropdown.is(':hidden'))
            dropdown.removeAttr('style');
    })
});
```

Есть куча разных методов - `onmouseover`, `onmouseout` и иже с ними. Какой мне больше подходит и как мне вообще реализовать нужный мне функционал?

Comment: Если вы не перехватили `mouseout` событие элемента, то как оно должно закрыться после отведения курсора? Я как то не могу понять

Comment: Посмотрите на документацию по `.hover()`. Он может принимать две функции на вход и выход мыши

Comment: И вообще, создайте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы хоть воспроизвести проблему можно было.

Comment: @AGS17 пожалуйста, https://jsfiddle.net/JamesJGoodwin/x2tbffxz/

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan я кое-что пробовал, но ничего не заработало.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin ну так дайте пример работу которого можем здесь посмотреть

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan я же скинул выше ссылку на JSfiddle.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin да конечно но здесь на сайте вы то же можете дать рабочий код, и если кто то видит ваш вопрос лучше что бы это было на виду, человеку так понятнее

Answer (score 0):

Вот добавил к вашему коду обработчик события `mouseleave`(курсор уходит за границы элемента), для `.dropdown-list` и все заработало так как вы хотели:

```js
$(() => {
    let dropdown = $('li .menu-link.drop-down'),
        itemlist = $('.menu-item-list'),
        w = $(window).width();

    dropdown.on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    dropdown.mouseover(function(e){
        //e.stopPropagation();
        let droplist = $(this).closest('li').find('.dropdown-list'),
            isHidden = droplist.is(':hidden');
        itemlist.find('.dropdown-list').removeClass('active')
        
        droplist.toggleClass('active')
    });
  $('.dropdown-list').mouseleave(function(e){
     $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        let neighbor = $('li .menu-link ~ .dropdown-list');
        if(w > 992 && dropdown.is(':hidden'))
            dropdown.removeAttr('style');
    })
});
```

```css
ul.menu-item-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
ul.menu-item-list {
 transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 float: right;
}
.top-nav.scroll-bot ul.menu-item-list {
 opacity: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
}
ul.menu-item-list, ul.menu-item-list li {
 margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
ul.menu-item-list li {
 list-style-type: none;
}
ul.menu-item-list li .menu-link {
 position: relative;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
 padding: 21px 20px;
 font-weight: 400;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 -webkit-transition: color 0s;
 transition: color 0s;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
 transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
}
ul.menu-item-list li .menu-link.drop-down {
 padding-right: 34px;
}
ul.menu-item-list li .menu-link.drop-down:after {
 font-family: 'Material Icons';
    content: 'keyboard_arrow_down';
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
 transform: translate(0,-50%);
 top: 50%;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.21);
    font-size: 1.27rem;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown-list {
    position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 background: transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.6);
 box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
 background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
 border-radius: 2px;
 -o-transition: opacity .1s linear, top 100ms linear, visibility .4s linear, transform .4s ease;
    transition: opacity .1s linear, top 100ms linear, visibility .4s linear, transform .4s ease;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-2em);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2em);
    transform: translateY(-2em);
 z-index: -1;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.dropdown-list .menu-items {
 position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 12;
    background: #fff;
 padding: 5px 0;
}
.dropdown-list.active {
 z-index: 1001;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.dropdown-list a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 color: #455a64;
 font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: padding .25s;
 transition: padding .25s;
}
.top-nav.minimized .dropdown-list {
 border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px
}
ul.dropdown-list li {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-list a:hover {
 background: white;
 color: #85B7D9;
}
.dropdown-list a i {
 padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
 max-width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-item-list desktop-menu">
    <li>
     <a href="#" class="menu-link drop-down">Билеты</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <div class="arrow-up"></div>
      <div class="menu-items">
       <li><a href="/special-offers/"><i style="color: #ff6f00;" class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Спецпредложения</a></li>
       <li><a href="/popular-directions/"><i style="color: #ffb300;" class="material-icons">star_rate</i>Популярные рейсы</a></li>
      </div>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#" class="menu-link drop-down">Информация</a>
     <div class="dropdown-list">
      <div class="arrow-up"></div>
      <div class="menu-items">
       <a href="/airlines/"><i style="color: #039be5;" class="material-icons">business_center</i>Авиакомпании</a>
       <a href="/airports/"><i style="color: #f44336;" class="material-icons">place</i>Аэропорты</a>
       <a href="/aircrafts/"><i style="color: #90a4ae;" class="material-icons">airplanemode_active</i>Самолёты</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#" class="menu-link drop-down">Компания</a>
     <div class="dropdown-list">
      <div class="arrow-up"></div>
      <div class="menu-items">
       <a href="/about/"><i style="color: #8bc34a;" class="material-icons">info</i>О нас</a>
       <a href="/help/"><i style="color: #1e88e5;" class="material-icons">help</i>Поддержка</a>
       <a href="/contacts/"><i style="color: #607d8b;" class="material-icons">email</i>Контакты</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Так ничего же не изменилось. Выпадающее меню как оставалось открытым, так и остаётся.